# Convert XML to JSON which should support if the xml tag has attributes in go programming?

Tags: json, xml, go

I want to create JSON from XML vice versa, so I got stuck at the point if XML contains the attributes  e.g. `<name id = "12"> Stack <name>`
so if this type of XML came how can I solve it.

I have searched on the internet I got this code from this site but it doesn't fill my requirement

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type DataFormat struct {
    ProductList []struct {
        Sku      string `xml:"sku" json:"sku"`
        Quantity int    `xml:"quantity" json:"quantity"`
    } `xml:"Product" json:"products"`
}

func main() {
    xmlData := []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ProductList>
    <Product>
        <sku >ABC123</sku>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <sku>ABC123</sku>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </Product>
</ProductList>`)

    data := &DataFormat{}
    err := xml.Unmarshal(xmlData, data)
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println("Error unmarshalling from XML", err)
        return
    }

    result, err := json.Marshal(data)
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println("Error marshalling to JSON", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", result)
}
```

this solution is working on a given sample XML but failed if the XML tag has attributes.

what do I need to modify in this code so that it works for XML which has attributes?

### Edit solution:

From the comment i got to know that i need to add `atrr` and `omitempty` option then it will work and for marking of attributes i can use `@` or `$`

sample code modification would be for my question:

```
type DataFormat struct {
    ProductList []struct {
        Id       string `xml:"id,attr,omitempty" json:"@id,omitempty"`
        Sku      string `xml:"sku" json:"sku"`
        Quantity int    `xml:"quantity" json:"quantity"`
    } `xml:"Product" json:"products"`
}
```

Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Use the `,attr` option in the xml tag. https://go.dev/play/p/XuJVzGJhPKS

Comment: @mkopriva but it will loose the information of attributes if want again back the same XML from that json?

Comment: Have you tried it? If yes show the code you've tried and explain the problem. If not then just try it.

Comment: yes I have tried your given solution but I want the JSON like this ```{
"test": [
      {
        "@id": "1",
         "name": "user1",
       },
       {
         "name": "user2",
       }
     ]
}```

Comment: @ tag or any other standard tag for attributes

Comment: Maybe change the json tag from `id` to `@id`?

Comment: if i change that ```id``` to ```@id``` still I will get empty ```@id``` in other keys of JSON, like in your code link first field has the ```id``` value but in the second still empty ```id``` tag is present

Comment: And don't show the code in comments. Update your question with the code that you are running. And also **show** the expected output.

Comment: The `@id` properties in the other json objects are empty because in the playground example that I provided only one `Product` XML element has the `id` attribute. If you want all json objects to have `@id` properties, then you have add `id` attributes to all `Product` elements. Quite simple really. And if you don't like empty attributes then use the `,omitempty` option. That option works for both `json` and `xml` tags. https://go.dev/play/p/9q25CM9CCOk

Comment: got it now, thank you so much